# About multiple event containers

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager

I am facing issue regarding to multiple event containers against single trigger.
when i firing one trigger in gtm then in ga4 against that event it counts three.
in gtm it's also showing tag fires in three containers of that evententer image description here(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r83oD.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rv9v.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0udb.png)

i have tried all posible aspects which were in my knowledge.
check either there are multiple gtm code in website etc.
find no proper solution against it.

Comment: Yes there are three `purchase` event on the left side as the datalayer push. Can you check why there has 3 purchase events?

Comment: no there is only one event of purchase in ga4

Comment: So can you confirm the purchase is triggered by `gtag()` ?. Or maybe you can share all of the purchase event and what is the data inside. ( you can blur the sensitive information but keep the parameter visible.)